# shell bash get file path and put into sub-directory

Tags: bash, shell

i have a long string in each line, one line like,

**1000 AS34_59329 RICwdsRSYHSD11-2-IPAAPEK-93 /ifshk5/BC_IP/PROJECT/T11073/T11073_RICekkR/Fq/AS34_59329/111220_I631_FCC0E5EACXX_L4_RICwdsRSYHSD11-2-IPAAPEK-93_1.fq.gz /ifshk5/BC_IP/PROJECT/T11073/T11073_RICekkR/Fq/AS34_59329/111220_I631_FCC0E5EACXX_L4_RICwdsRSYHSD11-2-IPAAPEK-93_2.fq.gz /ifshk5/BC_IP/PROJECT/T11073/T11073_RICekkR/Fq/AS34_59329/clean_111220_I631_FCC0E5EACXX_L4_RICwdsRSYHSD11-2-IPAAPEK-93_1.fq.gz.total.info 11.824 0.981393 43.8283 95.7401 OK**

this line contains three file locations(bold parts), i need to scp those files to another location like /sample . and also create sub-directory to put files, like this line files put into AS34_59329. so need create /sample/AS34_59329
Maybe many lines' sub-directory name is the same, so it need to judge whether the sub-directory has already create.
how to auto create the sub-directory?

```
 #! /bin/bash
 while read myline  
 do  
   for i in $myline
      do 
     if [ -f $i]; then
    scp -r $i xxxx@192.168.174.33:/sample
     fi
      done
 done < data.list
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have ssh keys, so if you ssh then remote  commands will work for you

```
 if [ -f $i]; then
     ssh xxxx@192.168.174.33 '[ -d /sample ]  && echo "OK" || mkdir /sample'
     scp -r $i xxxx@192.168.174.33:/sample
 fi
```

This will only work if you have privilege on the remote box  to create /sample.

Comment: i means create AS34_59329 directory in sample, in example line